# How do i insert value to datetimepicker by clicking datagridview cells in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, datagridview, datetimepicker

I was wondering if it's possible to set the value of a `datetimepicker` just by clicking selected row of datagridview.. and the format i want is `dd-MM-yyyy`. I tried ‍`dateTime.Parse()‍‍` but it gave me errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below code on datagridview OnCellClick:

```
    private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["The Column"].Value);
    }
```

Comment: this code works but it only converts the current time to the datettimepicker's value...

Comment: Hi Joe, I have edited my post. This will set the value of your datetime picker everytime you select a cell inside the gridview.

Comment: Hey Cedric, I'm sorry but i've tried the following code and it seems to set the current time and date to the dateTimePicker's value not the time and date in the datagridview.

Comment: Ok, Again, I've edited the code. You can check it on your end.